# Merge sort with pointer to pointer array not working

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, mergesort

Hello I've got this implementation of merge sort:

```
    void merge(Person **arr[], int firstElement, int midElement, int lastElement)
{
    int firstHalfSize = midElement - firstElement + 1;
    int secondHalfSize = lastElement - midElement;
    Person *firstHalfArray[firstHalfSize];
    Person *secondHalfArray[secondHalfSize];

    char *p;
    char *s;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstHalfSize; i++)
    {
        firstHalfArray[i] = *arr[firstElement + i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < secondHalfSize; j++)
    {
        secondHalfArray[j] = *arr[midElement + 1+ j];

    }

    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int mergedArrIndex = firstElement;

    while (index1 < firstHalfSize && index2 < secondHalfSize)
    {

        if ((*firstHalfArray)[index1].id <= (*secondHalfArray)[index2].id)
        {
            arr[mergedArrIndex] = &firstHalfArray[index1];
            index1++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[mergedArrIndex] = &secondHalfArray[index2];
            index2++;
        }
        mergedArrIndex++;
    }

    while (index1 < firstHalfSize)
    {
        arr[mergedArrIndex] = &firstHalfArray[index1];
        mergedArrIndex++;
        index1++;
    }

    while(index2 < secondHalfSize)
    {
        arr[mergedArrIndex] = &secondHalfArray[index2];
        mergedArrIndex++;
        index2++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(Person **arr, int firstElement, int lastElement)
{
    if (firstElement < lastElement)
    {
        int midElement = (firstElement + lastElement) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, firstElement, midElement);
        mergeSort(arr, midElement + 1, lastElement);
        merge(&arr, firstElement, midElement, lastElement);

    }
}
```

And a pointer to a an array of structs that is `Person *arrPersons`
The struct of person is as the following:

```
typedef struct Person
{
    char name[MAX_LENGTH_LINE];
    long id;
    float age;
} Person;
```

I'm calling the function in the main with:

```
mergeSort(&arrPersons, 0, 19);
```

(I have a list of 20 persons) where arrPersons is defined as  `Person *arrPersons`
And I'm trying to sort all of those persons by their id. I don't see why my merge sort is failing, I keep receiving a segmentation fault. Thank you for your help

Comment: "I don't see why my merge sort is failing, I keep receiving a segmentation fault." -- You may want to read these two links: 1. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) 2. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471)

Comment: Have you used a debugger to determine where exactly in your program the segmentation fault is occuring? And have you inspected the values of all variables at that location to determine whether they have expected values?

Comment: Although I don't want to encourage you to ask other people to debug your programs for you, it would be easier for other people to help you if you provided a [mre] in which you call the function `merge` with data that reliably produces a segmentation fault.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the segmentation fault with a small amount of data (for example 5 persons instead of 20 persons), then your program will also be easier to debug. You will be able to run your program line by line in a debugger, while monitoring the values of all variables, to see if they have the expected values.

Comment: regarding: ` Person *arrPersons`  This does NOT define an array of 20 `Person` elements.  Did you use something like `arrPersons = malloc( sizeof( Person ) * 20 );` ?

Comment: where/what is the definition of: `MAX_LENGTH_LINE`?

Comment: regarding: `char *p;` and `char *s;`   These two variables are not used, why show them to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_LENGTH_LINE 50


typedef struct Person
{
    char name[MAX_LENGTH_LINE];
    long id;
    float age;
} Person;
 
 
void merge(Person **arr[], int firstElement, int midElement, int lastElement)
{
    int firstHalfSize  = midElement  - firstElement + 1;
    int secondHalfSize = lastElement - midElement;
    Person *firstHalfArray[firstHalfSize];
    Person *secondHalfArray[secondHalfSize];

    //char *p;
    //char *s;

    for (int i = 0; i < firstHalfSize; i++)
    {
        firstHalfArray[i] = *arr[firstElement + i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < secondHalfSize; j++)
    {
        secondHalfArray[j] = *arr[midElement + 1+ j];

    }

    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int mergedArrIndex = firstElement;

    while (index1 < firstHalfSize && index2 < secondHalfSize)
    {

        if ((*firstHalfArray)[index1].id <= (*secondHalfArray)[index2].id)
        {
            arr[mergedArrIndex] = &firstHalfArray[index1];
            index1++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[mergedArrIndex] = &secondHalfArray[index2];
            index2++;
        }
        mergedArrIndex++;
    }

    while (index1 < firstHalfSize)
    {
        arr[mergedArrIndex] = &firstHalfArray[index1];
        mergedArrIndex++;
        index1++;
    }

    while(index2 < secondHalfSize)
    {
        arr[mergedArrIndex] = &secondHalfArray[index2];
        mergedArrIndex++;
        index2++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(Person **arr, int firstElement, int lastElement)
{
    if (firstElement < lastElement)
    {
        int midElement = (firstElement + lastElement) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, firstElement, midElement);
        mergeSort(arr, midElement + 1, lastElement);
        merge(&arr, firstElement, midElement, lastElement);

    }
}



int main( void )
{
    Person *arrPersons;
    arrPersons = malloc( sizeof( Person ) * 20 );
    
    mergeSort(&arrPersons, 0, 19);
}
```

The following is the output of running the program via  `gdb`

```
gdb untitled2
....

(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0xa3b: file untitled2.c, line 87.

(gdb) r
Starting program: untitled2 

Breakpoint 1, main () at untitled2.c:87
87  {

(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554827 in merge (arr=0x7fffffffde88, firstElement=0, midElement=0, 
    lastElement=1) at untitled2.c:33

33          secondHalfArray[j] = *arr[midElement + 1+ j];
(gdb) bt

#0  0x0000555555554827 in merge (arr=0x7fffffffde88, firstElement=0, 
    midElement=0, lastElement=1) at untitled2.c:33
#1  0x0000555555554a30 in mergeSort (arr=0x7fffffffdf70, firstElement=0, 
    lastElement=1) at untitled2.c:79
#2  0x0000555555554a04 in mergeSort (arr=0x7fffffffdf70, firstElement=0, 
    lastElement=2) at untitled2.c:77
#3  0x0000555555554a04 in mergeSort (arr=0x7fffffffdf70, firstElement=0, 
    lastElement=4) at untitled2.c:77
#4  0x0000555555554a04 in mergeSort (arr=0x7fffffffdf70, firstElement=0, 
    lastElement=9) at untitled2.c:77
#5  0x0000555555554a04 in mergeSort (arr=0x7fffffffdf70, firstElement=0, 
    lastElement=19) at untitled2.c:77
#6  0x0000555555554a6e in main () at untitled2.c:91
(gdb) 

line 77 mergeSort(arr, firstElement, midElement);
Line 79 merge(&arr, firstElement, midElement, lastElement);
Line 33 secondHalfArray[j] = *arr[midElement + 1+ j];

Where
j = 0
```

The above should be all you need to know to fix the program.

Note: I did not give the fields of the array of `Person` any specific values.

suggest reading: [merge sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/)

One thing to note is there is no usage of `**` in the passing of parameters

Answer (score 1):

### What happened?

Applying `&` to an array will result to a **pointer to array**. So `&arrPersons` is pointer to array of `Person`.
Applying `&` to a pointer to array will result to a **pointer to pointer to array**. That is what really passed into `merge`. So `arr` in `merge` is a pointer pointed to a **single element** of pointer to array. So accessing `arr` with an offset other than zero will cause index out of range error.

### Pass-by-value

Normally, parameters in C function is pass-by-value like:

```
void f(int x);
f(val);
```

The caller copy the value before passing it to `f`. So changing `x` in `f` does not effect `val` in the caller.

### Pass-by-reference

Some functions need to change a variable in the caller. They should pass the argument by reference.

In C, the famous way for pass-by-reference is to pass pointer to the function like:

```
void f(int *p);
f(&val);
```

`p` is a pointer. So `f` can access `val` by `*p`.

**Note**:
Fundamentally, there is no pass-by-reference. Passing pointer can do the almost same thing as pass-by-reference. But exactly, it's passing the **value** of the pointer.

### How to pass an array by reference to a function?

Array will decay into a pointer when passing it. [c-fqa 6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html):

> A reference to an object of type array-of-T which appears in an expression decays (with three exceptions) into a pointer to its first element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T.

So direct passing a array to a function acept pointer is fine.

e.g. consider the sample code:

```
void f(int *p);
int a[4];
f(a);
```

`a` can be directly passing to f.
And in the function `f`, `p` will be a pointer pointed to the first element of `a`.

### In this case

Take pointer to an array is not necessary. Just passing the array to the function will work well.

Comment: `"pointer of array"` -> `"pointer to array"` (nit) "Pass by Reference" - In C there is no pass by reference. You are passing an address by value simulating a pass by reference. That is an important distinction. (I know what you mean, but the OP may take you literally) Better to link to the C standard for a question tagged C. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am just confused, after googling, I find that some pages like [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) and [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/) use both "pointer of" and "pointer to". But using "pointer to" more. Does they have different meaning? Or just "pointer to" is more common, so i can replace all "pointer of" to "pointer to".

Comment: "pointer of" what? A pointer is a normal variable that holds the address to another object as its value. (i.e. the pointer "points to" where the other object can be found in memory) Simple case `int a = 5, b = &a;` There `b` holds the address of `a` as its value (we say `b` points to `a`). I know what you mean, and I suspect this may also be a language `to` and `of` translation issue, but generally we say a pointer `"points to"` a memory address rather than being a `"pointer of"` that address.  Be wary of what you read in general from the internet unless it is from the actual standard.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for explanation. And sorry for the wrong link, C has the same thing, but this answer should like to C version. I will edit it.

Comment: Glad to help. This is a fantastic site for the discussion of programming information -- that's how we all learn `:)`

Comment: "In C, the famous way for pass-by-reference is to pass pointer" -- This implies that there are also other ways to pass references in C. Is that true?

Comment: One thing I don't like about using the term "pass by reference" is that, although it is not wrong, it can be confused with C++.  In C++, there are three ways to pass variables to functions: "pass by value", "pass by pointer" and "pass by reference". The first two were taken over from C and the third one is a C++ extension, as C++ introduced references as an abstraction of pointers. Therefore, since most C programmers also know C++ to a certain extent, it is confusing to use the term "pass by reference" in C.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel When passing by pointer, what really wanted is passing by reference, [pass by value vs. pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/10330005). In other words, a pointer is **a reference to the memory address**. I know that is confusing with the C++ type reference. But without comparing the two concept "pass by value" and "pass by reference", it's difficult for me to explain how to pass and edit an array in a function.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel There may are other ways for pass-by-reference. But, I don't know. Saying "the famous" because it's not exactly passing a refence but passing the value of a pointer. Thanks for help, and I may try to edit it to be less confusing. `:)`

Comment: @yao99: The only other way I can think of passing by reference without passing by pointer is to pass an integer index to an element in a global array. However, that is rather far-fetched, so not worth mentioning. I have upvoted your answer, even though I have the concerns mentioned above about certain formulations in your answer. However, you are right that "pass by reference" is the more general term, even if it is confusing in C++.